# How to seperate semicolon delimited values from a column in SQL Server and put them in multiple rows?

Tags: sql-server

I need to separate a Semicolon Delimited values from a column and put them in different rows. For that I created a function, but I do not know how to map it with the table.

The Function is as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION  [dbo].[String_Split] 



(


@InputString                  VARCHAR(8000),

@Delimiter                    VARCHAR(50)


)

RETURNS @Items TABLE 

(

Item                          VARCHAR(8000)

)

AS
BEGIN

      IF @Delimiter = ' '
      BEGIN
            SET @Delimiter = ';'
            SET @InputString = REPLACE(@InputString, ' ', @Delimiter)
      END

      IF (@Delimiter IS NULL OR @Delimiter = '')
            SET @Delimiter = ';'

      DECLARE @Item           VARCHAR(8000)
      DECLARE @ItemList       VARCHAR(8000)
      DECLARE @DelimIndex     INT

      SET @ItemList = @InputString
      SET @DelimIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @ItemList, 0)
      WHILE (@DelimIndex != 0)
      BEGIN
            SET @Item = SUBSTRING(@ItemList, 0, @DelimIndex)
            INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@Item)

                       SET @ItemList = SUBSTRING(@ItemList, @DelimIndex+1, LEN(@ItemList)-@DelimIndex)
            SET @DelimIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @ItemList, 0)
      END 

      IF @Item IS NOT NULL -- At least one delimiter was encountered in @InputString
      BEGIN
            SET @Item = @ItemList
            INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@Item)
      END

      @InputString
      ELSE INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@InputString)

      RETURN

END 

GO

Table Example:

CREATE TABLE dbo.Table

AS
BEGIN

SELECT a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,l,m

FROM Table

END

GO
```

**Currently I am using SQL Server 2014 version.**

I am getting the data from different sources and dumped in to the tables in SQL Server. Some of the above columns contain Semicolon separated values lets just say c,e,g columns have Semicolon separated values and I want to separate them and put them in different rows.

I want to achieve this by mapping the Function with the table or the stored procedure that I have already created.

I am stuck in the middle of my project, Can any one please help me with this process?

Comment: That looping procedure will perform horribly at scale. I'd use [one like this](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) instead. What do you mean map it to a table? `insert into Tabe select * from YourFunction()` doesn't work for you?

Comment: I have to include it in the stored procedure, so that it will separate the delimited values when ever I execute the procedure.

Comment: You first need to create a function to split string as **string_split** is only available since 2016

Comment: Hello Daniel, I already created the String_Split Function and also included it in my question. Can you please take a look in to it and let me know if there are any corrections that I have to make it to work more effectively, and how to join it with the stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple technique that I use all the time. I simply convert the delimited list to XML and go from there. You should be able to modify it for your need:

```
-- Sample List --
DECLARE @list VARCHAR(255) = 'VALOE01;VALUE02;VALUE03;VALUE04;VALUE05';

-- Select table of values --
DECLARE @xml XML = CAST( '<x><v>' + REPLACE( @list, ';', '</v><v>' ) + '</v></x>' AS XML );
SELECT x.f.value( '.', 'VARCHAR(50)' ) AS [value] FROM @xml.nodes( '//x/v' ) x( f );
```

Returns

```
+---------+
|  value  |
+---------+
| VALOE01 |
| VALUE02 |
| VALUE03 |
| VALUE04 |
| VALUE05 |
+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try call function with CROSS APPLY like this:

```
   SELECT splitA.value FROM @Table CROSS APPLY string_split(a,';') as splitA
```

Full example:

```
  CREATE FUNCTION  [dbo].[String_Split] 
  (
  @InputString                  VARCHAR(8000),
  @Delimiter                    VARCHAR(50)
  )

  RETURNS @Items TABLE 
  (
  Item                          VARCHAR(8000)
  )

  AS
  BEGIN

  IF @Delimiter = ' '
  BEGIN
        SET @Delimiter = ';'
        SET @InputString = REPLACE(@InputString, ' ', @Delimiter)
  END

  IF (@Delimiter IS NULL OR @Delimiter = '')
        SET @Delimiter = ';'

  DECLARE @Item           VARCHAR(8000)
  DECLARE @ItemList       VARCHAR(8000)
  DECLARE @DelimIndex     INT

  SET @ItemList = @InputString
  SET @DelimIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @ItemList, 0)
  WHILE (@DelimIndex != 0)
  BEGIN
        SET @Item = SUBSTRING(@ItemList, 0, @DelimIndex)
        INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@Item)

        SET @ItemList = SUBSTRING(@ItemList, @DelimIndex+1,            
        LEN(@ItemList)-@DelimIndex)
        SET @DelimIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @ItemList, 0)
  END 

  IF @Item IS NOT NULL -- At least one delimiter was encountered in @InputString
  BEGIN
        SET @Item = @ItemList
        INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@Item)
  END


  ELSE INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@InputString)

  RETURN

  END 

  GO



  DECLARE @Table TABLE (a nvarchar(200),  b nvarchar(200))


  INSERT INTO @Table (a,b)
  VALUES ('a1;a2;a3;a4;a5','b1,b2,b3,b4,b5')
        ,('a11;a12;a13;a14;a15','b11,b12,b13,b14,b15')

  SELECT splitA.value FROM @Table
  CROSS APPLY string_split(a,';') as splitA
```